# JAXB: partial unmarshalling returns empty domain object

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm trying to **unmarshal** a (well-formed) **part** of a **xml** string using the "partial jaxb unmarshaling" technique, described in the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12076303/unmarshall-part-of-xml-to-an-object).

For this I'm using a subset of a JAXB domain models (which have been created by xjc) of the corresponding XML schema. This subset corresponds exactly to the part xml string which the `XMLStreamReader` processes.

After ensuring that the `XMLStreamReader` position is correct (which is in fact the first element), I'm invoking

```
 Unmarshaller unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(jaxbModelClass)
          .createUnmarshaller();

 return unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, jaxbModelClass).getValue();
```

This is done without any exception and the returned object is indeed an instance of `jaxbModelClass`, however it's **not containing any child elements** (all are set to `null`).

What is the cause of this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the XML you are unmarshalling?

Comment: Due to legal reasons, I cannot provide the original xml/xsd. If it cannot be avoided, I'll try to build a minimalistic alternative. However, I traced through the unmarshalling, it seems to be a namespace issue. The first tag in the part xml can be resolved, but for the first child, no childUnmarshaller could be found (due to an empty uri)  hence a Discarder is used. What makes me wonder is: if it's a namespace issue, why is the first tag (which is part of the same namespace as its child) resolved at all?

Comment: I have added an answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22859383/383861

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of how you can handle this use case.

### XML

Below is the XML document we will use.  The partial document we will unmarshal starts at the `bar` element.  It doesn't matter if the class is created by hand or generated from an XML Schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo xmlns="http://www.example.com">
    <bar>
        <baz>Hello World</baz>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

### Java Model

**Bar**

This is the class we will unmarshal.  Note that it doesn't have an `@XmlRootElement` annotation.

```
package forum22818252;

public class Bar {

    private String baz;

    public String getBaz() {
        return baz;
    }

    public void setBaz(String baz) {
        this.baz = baz;
    }

}
```

**package-info**

Since our XML document is namespace qualified we will use the package level `@XmlSchema` annotation (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html).

```
@XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.example.com",
    elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package forum22818252;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
```

### Demo Code

**Demo**

Below we will parse the document with a StAX `XMLStreamReader`.  Then we advance the `XMLStreamReader` to the local root we wish to unmarshal.  And finally since our class does not have a root element associated with it we will use an unmarshal method that takes a `Class` parameter.

```
package forum22818252;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
        StreamSource source = new StreamSource("src/forum22818252/input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(source);
        while(!(xsr.isStartElement() && "bar".equals(xsr.getLocalName()))) {
            xsr.next();
        }

        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bar.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        Bar bar = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xsr, Bar.class).getValue();

        System.out.println(bar.getBaz());
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code.

```
Hello World
```